# Push FILES (not messages) from backend server to an android app using PHP

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I went through [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) tutorial and was successfully able to send push messages from the server to my Android app. How can I send any file from the server to my app in the same way. I am using Google Cloud Messaging service.

Comment: How about just send the ID of the file and then GET the file (two steps)

Comment: You need to implement file service to get the files from the server. Server has to be some logic to serve you files that android application wants..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Google Cloud Messaging you can send to device very small block of data, so I think it's impossible to transport file's content with push. But you can send link to the file or file id in the push data block and background service in your aplication will start download after receiving this push.